# how to solve age problems in algebra maths?

Tags: math, algebra

This is an problem regarding age. I don't know how to solve this problem. Please help me. The problem is

> ```
> > A man is 5 times as old as his son. 2 years ago the sum of squares of
> > their ages was 11, 14. find the present age of son?
> ```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: whoa.. is that a homework problem?

Answer (score 3):

Not really a programming question.. but hey, I think every programmer needs some math skills at his disposal.

Since this looks like a homework problem .. let me give you some pointers.

```
A man is 5 times as old as his son
```

Son's age = x, Man's age = 5x

```
2 years ago the sum of squares of their ages was 1114 (I think)
```

(x-2)<sup>2</sup> + (5x-2)<sup>2</sup> = 1114

Solve for x!!